How to change the asyncio event loop policy when using Azure Functions?
I am using Azure Functions and python to connect to a PostgreSQL database. I would like to use the psycopg3 library and an AsyncConnectionPool  to do so.
psycopg requires you to change the default event loop policy (e.g. with asyncio.set_event_loop_policy(asyncio.WindowsSelectorEventLoopPolicy())), which I do but I still get errors. I think this is because the asyncio policy gets set before I get the chance to call asyncio.set_event_loop_policy(). How can I work around this? I could use non-async connections if I needed to, but I'd rather stick with async for the performance benefits.
Code to reproduce:
#function_app.py

import azure.functions as func
import psycopg_pool
import json
import asyncio
import os

if os.name == 'nt':
    asyncio.set_event_loop_policy(asyncio.WindowsSelectorEventLoopPolicy())

con_str = "host=localhost dbname=test-db user=postgres password=admin"
apool = psycopg_pool.AsyncConnectionPool(
            conninfo=con_str,
            open = False
        )

app = func.FunctionApp(http_auth_level=func.AuthLevel.FUNCTION)

async def connect():
    await apool.open()
    await apool.wait()
    print("Connect OK")

@app.route(route="info", auth_level= func.AuthLevel.FUNCTION)
async def info_trigger(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    try:
        await connect()
        status = {"test": "OK"}
    except:
        status = {"test": "Not ok"}
    return func.HttpResponse(
        json.dumps(status),
        status_code=200,
        mimetype='application/json'
    )

if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(connect())


If I run function_app.py from command line (py function_app.py) I get the "Connect OK" printout as expected.
If I launch the server locally with func host start and send a request via postman, I get {test: "Not ok"} as a response and the console that I launched the host from repeats the following printout:
error connecting in 'pool-1': Psycopg cannot use the 'ProactorEventLoop' to run in async mode. Please use a compatible event 
loop, for instance by setting 'asyncio.set_event_loop_policy(WindowsSelectorEventLoopPolicy())'


You could try to set this in __init__.py:
/ function_app_folder
    ├─ __init__.py
    ├─ function_app.py

__init__.py:
import asyncio
import os

if os.name == 'nt':
    asyncio.set_event_loop_policy(asyncio.WindowsSelectorEventLoopPolicy())

And remove this code from function_app.py.
By placing it in __init__.py you ensures, that policy setting before function_app.py

Thank you for the response. I tried this method but I still get the same error. Logging asyncio.get_event_loop_policy() prints <asyncio.windows_events.WindowsProactorEventLoopPolicy object at ... so it looks like __init__.py is not being called. Is there something I need to configure first? I am using the programming model v2 if that makes a difference.

__init__.py calling first for each module of python project. Could you please provide full tree structure of your project?

I'm able to run the same code after removing await apool.wait() from async def connect(): in your code.
Modified code as below:
import asyncio
import json
import os

import azure.functions as func
import psycopg_pool

if os.name == 'nt':
    asyncio.set_event_loop_policy(asyncio.WindowsSelectorEventLoopPolicy())

con_str = "host=hostname dbname=dbName user=User password=password"
apool = psycopg_pool.AsyncConnectionPool(
            conninfo=con_str,
            open=False
        )

app = func.FunctionApp()

async def connect():
    await apool.open()
    print("Connect OK")

@app.route(route="info", auth_level= func.AuthLevel.FUNCTION)
async def info_trigger(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    try:
        await connect()
        status = {"test": "OK"}
    except:
        status = {"test": "Not ok"}
    return func.HttpResponse(
        json.dumps(status),
        status_code=200,
        mimetype='application/json'
    )

if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(connect())


Able to run the function as expected:

Console Output:

Response:

